# How to show editor in frontend of Joomla 2.5 custom component

Tags: php, joomla, editor

I am unable to add editor to my frontend in my custom component and unable to find any help online as well. Is it supposed to be something really simple?

I got this code from somewhere but even this is showing simple textarea, I have also checked the user's editor option and tried setting it to TinyMCE manually but it still shows simple plain textarea

```
        jimport( 'joomla.html.editor' );
        $editor =& JEditor::getInstance();
        echo $editor->display("jobdesc", ""/*$itemData['body']*/, "400", "100", "150", "10", 1, null, null, null, array('mode' => 'advanced'));
```

Comment: How you add custom component in front end ... please guide me to display my custom component in front end ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the editor with JFactory.

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
echo $editor->display("jobdesc", ""/*$itemData['body']*/, "400", "100", "150", "10", 1, null, null, null, array('mode' => 'advanced'));
```

http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to do this, however now I am having the issue of styling, the tinyMCE goes beyond (in width) the other text boxes and nothing is helping reduce its width. I have tried CSS as well as decreasing height in parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: You can specify the width in pixel. Please try,
echo $editor->display("jobdesc", "some content", "100px");

Comment: Hi Joras, Thanks for the solution. Its not working modcontent

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file to create a form,you have to put "type=editor".